# Box2D Detecting when 2 specific edges touch

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision-detection, game-physics, box2d-iphone

I am working on a Cocos2D project using Box2D and I am trying to detect when 2 specific edges on an object touch, for example for the red edges in the images below:

[image]

I am still learning collisions but I understand the basics and how to detect if 2 specific bodies touch, but I cannot figure out how to detect specific edges.

One solution I thought of was to new create bodies on the edges that I want to detect, but I want to know when both red edges are completely aligned and the boxes form a rectangle.

There may be an easy way to do this but I scoured the internet and found no useful examples.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add two small fixtures to the relevant corners of each body like this, and check when the two pairs (red/red, blue/blue) are overlapping simultaneously. Circle fixtures would be fine, and resizing them is an easy way to adjust how precise the match needs to be.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the visual & help! I am going to attempt this and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Box2D detects collisions not between b2Bodies, but between b2Fixtures. All you need is add sensor fixture to your b2Bodies (`fexture.isSensor = YES`), set it's position to needed point (just 1-2 pixels to the right edge, out of your physical shape) and detect contacts for thise two sesors. I hope this was clear.